# Vaadin Custom Layouts + Bootstrap Theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vaadin

Because Vaadin provides [Custom Layouts](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html) I thought about using a Bootstrap Theme like [Unify](http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.9.3/index.html) for layouting and styling the application with HTML + CSS. The CustomLayout should "connect" my HTML templates with Vaadin.

I have a working HTML template (with JS & CSS file includes) that just work local in the browser. Is it possible to use Vaadin this way?

My CustomLayout would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Web Fonts -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>

    <!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- CSS Header and Footer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/headers/header-default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/footers/footer-v1.css">

    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- CSS Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme-colors/default.css" id="style_color">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme-skins/dark.css">

    <!-- CSS Customization -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>

    ...

    <!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/smoothScroll.js"></script>
    <!-- JS Customization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- JS Page Level -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            App.init();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: The vaadin CSS themes are very much adapted/optimized to the vaadin components. You won't have it working with bootstrap, unless it provides the correct vaadin class names in the css

Comment: You can embed Vaadin UIs on existing pages. https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html This will only give you bootstrap-look-and-feel on the elements outside the Vaadin UI's though ...